# In this Circular Slider code prev and Next function is not working properly

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I am currently making one J query Slider Which is working such that when u click next that will slide from right to left and when u click prev that will slide from left to right . the images are limited so that it will start shown the previous image in a circular manner. The problem is that The prev and next button on clicking is not working properly. I am unable to find out the best solution for it. Can any one suggest me what could be the best way to write it. Or is there any effective technique to make such slider without use of any slider plugins.

JQuery Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
var galW =  $('#gallery').width();  
var imgN = $('#slider img').length;
$("#slider").width((galW/6)*imgN);
$('#next').click(function(){    
    var first = $("#slider img").first();
    var last = $("#slider img").last();
    first.stop().animate({marginLeft : -150},1500,function(){
first.detach().insertAfter(last).css('marginLeft','0px');
});
});

$('#prev').click(function(){
        var first = $("#slider img").first();
    var last = $("#slider img").last();
    last.detach().insertBefore(first).css('marginLeft','-150px');
    first.stop().animate({marginLeft : 0},1500);
});
});
```

HTML Code

```
<div id="gallery">
            <div id="gallery_overflow">
                <div id="slider">
                    <img src="#" width="150px" height="50px"/>
                    <img src="#" width="150px" height="50px"/>
                    <img src="#" width="150px" height="50px"/>
                    <img src="#" width="150px" height="50px"/>
                                    <img src="#" width="150px" height="50px"/>
                                    <img src="#" width="150px" height="50px"/>
                                    <img src="#" width="150px" height="50px"/>
                                    <img src="#" width="150px" height="50px"/>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="prev"><img src="left.png" width="40px" height="40px"/></div>
            <div id="next"><img src="right.png" width="40px" height="40px"/></div>
        </div>
```

The Images are there in # Places ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some modifications of your code, you can make it work as follows *( to support links on images look below at the **EDIT** part)*,

**CSS**

```
#gallery{
    overflow:hidden;
}
#slider {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
#slider img {
     margin-left:5px; 
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var galW = $('#gallery').width();
    var imgN = $('#slider img').length;
    var sliding = false;
    $("#slider").width((galW / 6) * imgN);
    $('#next').click(function () {
        if(sliding)return;
        sliding = true;
        var first = $("#slider img").first();
        var last = $("#slider img").last();
        var defaultMarginLeft = first.css("margin-left");
        first.animate({
            marginLeft: (-1*first.width())
        }, 1500, function () {
            first.detach().insertAfter(last).css('marginLeft', defaultMarginLeft);
            sliding = false;
        });
    });

    $('#prev').click(function () {
        if(sliding)return;
        sliding = true;
        var first = $("#slider img").first();
        var last = $("#slider img").last();
        var defaultMarginLeft = first.css("margin-left");
        last.detach().insertBefore(first).css('marginLeft', (-1*first.width()));
        first = $("#slider img").first();
        first.animate({
            marginLeft: defaultMarginLeft
        }, 1500,function(){sliding=false;});
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2dwsW/

**EDIT**

Another implementation using span element as placeholder *(actually it is the class **placeholder** that is being used in selectors, therefore any inline block element can be used instead of span with this class name)* to properly support links on the images and also enable the inclusion of any element required.

**CSS**

```
#gallery{
    overflow:hidden;
}
#slider {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
#slider .placeholder {
     margin-left:5px; 
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var galW = $('#gallery').width();
    var imgN = $('#slider .placeholder').length;
    var sliding = false;
    $("#slider").width((galW / 6) * imgN);
    $('#next').click(function () {
        if(sliding)return;
        sliding = true;
        var first = $("#slider .placeholder").first();
        var last = $("#slider .placeholder").last();
        var defaultMarginLeft = first.css("margin-left");
        first.animate({
            marginLeft: (-1*first.width())
        }, 1500, function () {
            first.detach().insertAfter(last).css('marginLeft', defaultMarginLeft);
            sliding = false;
        });
    });

    $('#prev').click(function () {
        if(sliding)return;
        sliding = true;
        var first = $("#slider .placeholder").first();
        var last = $("#slider .placeholder").last();
        var defaultMarginLeft = first.css("margin-left");
        last.detach().insertBefore(first).css('marginLeft', (-1*first.width()));
        first = $("#slider .placeholder").first();
        first.animate({
            marginLeft: defaultMarginLeft
        }, 1500,function(){sliding=false;});
    });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="gallery">
    <div id="gallery_overflow">
        <div id="slider">
            <span class="placeholder"><a href=#><img src="http://placehold.it/150x50" /></a></span><span class="placeholder"><a href=#><img src="http://placehold.it/150x50" /></a></span><span class="placeholder"><a href=#><img src="http://placehold.it/150x50" /></a></span><span class="placeholder"><a href=#><img src="http://placehold.it/150x50" /></a></span><span class="placeholder"><a href=#><img src="http://placehold.it/150x50" /></a></span><span class="placeholder"><a href=#><img src="http://placehold.it/150x50" /></a></span><span class="placeholder"><a href=#><img src="http://placehold.it/150x50" /></a></span><span class="placeholder"><a href=#><img src="http://placehold.it/150x50" /></a></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="prev">PREV</div>
    <div id="next">NEXT</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2dwsW/1/

Comment: I got One problem when I tried to insert link on the images. For the first time links work fine. after that every thing got out of control

Comment: @Vinay Indeed if you place links on the images of the slide the selectors need to be modified a little. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Vinay please accept the answer to assist others as well, thank you.

Comment: Thanks Sir .. actually I am new here don't know how to accept it .. please assist me.